# How can I cast spells more quickly?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-blades

It seems that magic is very under-powered in Blades. Aside from Absorb, which seems to be one hell of a crutch to fall back on, other spells like Fire, Frost, and especially Poison, seem woefully under-powered. The main problem is that a large chunk of spells can be interrupted, meaning you have a very limited window in which to cast them.

Right now, the best thing (and best doesn't mean good here) to do is to time your block on an attack, then try to cast your spell while the enemy is recovering from your block. Not even this can be successful 100% of the time though, with many enemies, especially later in the game, recovering more quickly, or not reeling at all from a timed block.

My question is, is there any way in Blades that I can cast spells more quickly?

Comment: Yes, please. I've stopped leveling up the magic side because it never works.